# Find the matrix B such that it's null space is $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Find the matrix B such that it's null space is $V=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0),~(1,2,0),~(1,5,0)\}$.

Since this set of vectors is linearly dependent, I take $\operatorname{span}((1,1,0),~(1,2,0))$ as the linearly independent set. Then, if I think about special solutions, I'd have two, and one pivot variable. Since $(1,1,0)$ is the solution you get by considering $x_1=0,x_2=1$ and $(1,2,0)$ taking $x_1=1,x_2=0$, then the column with the only pivot of the matrix is the third one, $B^3=(0,0,1)^T$

However, I can't figure out how to complete the $3\times 3$ matrix using these special solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span of those three vectors is $S=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$. So, you can take $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. It is clear that\begin{align}B.(x,y,z)=0&\iff z=0\\&\iff(x,y,z)\in S.\end{align}

Comment: If it is a span, can I just use a general span like you did? I was trying to solve it using "special solutions"

Comment: Yes. After knowing which space your vectors span, there is no need to consider the vectors that spanned it.

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware about that but sounds logic. It also makes the problem simpler, thanks.

Comment: What if I must use special solutions?

Comment: Then you search for numbers $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$ such that$$(b_1,b_2b_3).(1,1,0)=(b_1,b_2b_3).(1,2,0)=(b_1,b_2b_3).(1,5,0)=0.$$

Comment: Right, definitely, straight to the definition of nullspace, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $T$ by $T(1,1,0)=T(1,2,0)=0$ and $T(0,0,1)=(x,y,z)$, where not all of $x,y,z$ are zero, you will have one.  Giving the values on a basis determine a linear transformation.

This $T$ will go from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: My knowledge on linear transformation isn't too much. Maybe for that reason I could not understand the relation between you answer and what I asked. By the way, in this problem I can't use linear transformations yet.

Comment: Ok.  The matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&x\\0&0&y\\0&0&z\end{pmatrix}$, rel the basis $\beta=\{(1,1,0),(1,2,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and the standard basis.